# How to make a plane with no color changes regardless of lighting conditions and have shadows cast on it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color, shadows

I wanted to ask how to have the material of a plane be consistent or on par with the color value given to it regardless of lighting conditions and have shadows cast onto it on render? The image will be rendered on Cycles.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. How can an object have a uniform color value regardless of lighting, but also have shadows? Wouldn't the shadowed areas represent a non-uniform color value?

Comment: Use a Shadow Catcher, and composite in the flat color in post?